# GameEngine BGE: Create a visible path from x/y coordinates via python script

Tags: python, mesh, game-engine

for my work I am using a simple animation, where a vehicle is moving over a concrete surface. The movement is either controlled manually for testing (WASD) or via a TCP-Input, where it receives x/y/z position and rotation.

I would like to add a feature where you can import a list of x/y/z-coordinates from a file at animation startup. This data is used to create a visible trajectory on the surface.

I am able to create a path mesh from the data but I can't find a way to make the mesh visible (probably as it is a line and its "width" is zero). I made this animation 5 years ago and kinda stumbled into doing it with blender so I am far from being an expert.

Below there is the code I use at startup to create the Path which I wrote with alot of googeling...

```
def main():
    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    own = cont.owner

    if not 'trajectory' in own:
        print('Creating trayectory...')
    
        own['trajectory'] = 1
        scene = bpy.context.scene

        # List is acutally much longer and from a ASCII-input
        coordinates = [(0.38537, -0.032496), (0.46504, -0.039214), (...)]

        mesh_data = bpy.data.meshes.new("PathMesh")
        path_object = bpy.data.objects.new("Path", mesh_data)  

        scene.objects.link(path_object)

        vertices = [(*coord, 0) for coord in coordinates]
        edges = [(i, i+1) for i in range(len(coordinates)-1)]

        mesh_data.from_pydata(vertices, edges, [])

        mesh_data.update()
        print('Trajectory created.')
```